# Term to describe how often someone meets their deadlines

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm designing a report that describes our software users' performance on their assignments. One data point is the percentage of assignments submitted on time. I've labeled this column "Timeliness," but I suspect there's a more appropriate word, and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: ***Punctuality***.

Comment: +1 on @DanBron’s *punctuality* also called *on-time performance* or *OTP* by the airlines. https://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/flights/todayinthesky/2016/01/07/airline-on-time-performance/78407958/

Comment: @Jim's suggestion is better because both *early* and *late* are antonyms of *punctual*, whereas meeting a deadline is ... something like **_prompt_**, perhaps? Or simply say **_in time_** rather than _on time_.

Comment: @WillCrawford - Note that the airline report is put out by the “Punctuality League”

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin This is for a user-facing report, so I want the column heading to make sense to the user. (And as a developer, I can tell you that when objects in code and in databases are named well, it makes my job a lot easier – so yes, it does matter.) Thanks for your input.

Comment: Agreed with @WillCrawford's point - punctuality isn't technically appropriate for deadlines, since submitting any time up to the deadline is fine. Punctuality is more appropriate for appointments etc. where there's a small window around a specific time. Your 'timeliness' is good, in that 'Timely' means 'happened at the right time'.